# Check membership user in group or tenant in camunda with Java API

Tags: spring-boot, camunda, bpmn, business-process-management

How can we get boolean result with Java API if a user is actually membership in some group or tenant in camunda. This is for exception handling and logic to not save duplicate users on groups and tenants. I know we neew `userService` but I not found that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure, but probably something like this should work:

```
private final IdentityService identityService;

private boolean isUserAMemberOfTenant(String userId, String tenantId) {
    return identityService.createUserQuery().userId(userId).memberOfTenant(tenantId).count() > 0;
}

private boolean isUserAMemberOfGroup(String userId, String groupId) {
    return identityService.createUserQuery().userId(userId).memberOfGroup(groupId).count() > 0;
}
```